# checkbox value stored in wrong place - php codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, checkbox

I fill my html table with these values in two rows. The row can be added dynamically.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/tc5OA.jpg

All the fields are working fine (they go to the proper place inside the database) except for the checkboxes. I checked 2 checkboxes for each row but the values all stored in the first row like this while the second row doesn't store the expected value.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/BB1QM.jpg

I named each field with array for example `<input name="category[]">`

**this is the controller**

```
foreach ($basic_category as $id => $key) {

        $basic_data = array(
            'id_number' => $id_number,
            'basic_category' => $basic_category[$id],
            'basic_workscope' => $basic_workscope[$id],
            'basic_i' => $basic_i[$id],
            'basic_e' => $basic_e[$id],
            'basic_pi' => $basic_pi[$id],
            'basic_pa' => $basic_pa[$id],
            'basic_ata_chapter' => $basic_ata_chapter[$id]
        );

        $this->mod->insert_t_basic($basic_data);

    }
```

**this is the model**

```
public function insert_t_basic($data) {

    $this->db->insert('t_basic', $data);

}
```

Please tell me if this is not clear enough or you want more details :)

Answer (score 0):

Please change all the field names in the below format

```
<input name="data[category][]">
<input name="data[basic_pi][]">
```

In the controller

```
$data = array();
foreach ($this->input->post('data') as $k => $v) {
     foreach ($v as $data_k => $data_v) {
         $data[$data_k][$k] = $data_v;
     }
}
if(count($data) > 0) {
    $this->mod->insert_t_basic($data);
}
```

In the model

```
$this->db->insert_batch('t_basic', $data);
```

Please try this Hope this helps. Thanks

Comment: Thank you for your time. Unfortunately, I got the following error : Severity: Notice

Message: Array to string conversion

Filename: database/DB_driver.php

Line Number: 1477

Comment: in the controller, please put print_r($data); exit; and tell me the result

Comment: are u still struggling?